# Installing Ubuntu on Mac using Windows to create bootable USB

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, mac

I want to install Ubuntu on my Mac. I do not have an OS installed on my Mac. How can I do that? Using Windows to create a bootable USB for Mac is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I wonder what was that downvote for? The OP has stated clearly that he owns a Mac with no OS on it. The OP wants to install Ubuntu on that Mac. And, in order to do that, he has to use another PC which has Windows on it. So, what's the problem in all this? I don't have a Mac myself, but, from what I read on AskUbuntu, Mac devices are quite unusual. So, for this OP the classical answer "Burn a CD/USB" is not quite enough.

Comment: Have you tried Unetbootin? That's what [Canonical's official instructions for Mac](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) recommend and it's cross-platform so it should work on Windows too. Drop me a line about your results so I can convert this into an answer or find an appropriate duplicate question.

Comment: Two links that might help (somehow) http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/installing-linux-on-a-late-2007-imac-without-cd-rom-drive.1986268/ and http://www.howtogeek.com/187410/how-to-install-and-dual-boot-linux-on-a-mac/